# Ionic nav bar buttons loading multiple times

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am having this issue where items placed in the `<ion-nav-buttons>` tag are being loaded multiple times.

This is a simplification of what I'm seeing, but it should be descriptive of the issue.

I made a simple directive for my application. The only thing that it does is prints some code to the console to let me know that it has loaded:

```
(function(){
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('opeapp')
            .directive('tester', tester);

    tester.$inject = [
  ];

    function tester($rootScope, $compile)
  {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
      link: link,
      scope: true,
        };

    function link(scope)
    {
      console.log('LOAD THIS');
    }
    }
})();
```

Then I have some HTML that looks like this:

```
<ion-side-menus enable-menu-with-back-views="true">
  <ion-side-menu-content drag-content="false">
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-clear">
      <ion-nav-back-button></ion-nav-back-button>
      <ion-header-bar class="bar-clear">
        <img ng-src="img/text_white.png" style="width: 100px; height: 12px; margin: auto;">
      </ion-header-bar>
      <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
        <tester></tester> //<--- *** THIS IS WHERE THE ISSUE IS HAPPENING
      </ion-nav-buttons>
    </ion-nav-bar>

    <!-- MAIN CONTENT -->
    <ion-nav-view name="mainContent"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-side-menu-content>

  <!-- SIDE MENU -->
  <ion-side-menu side="right">
        <ion-nav-view name="sideMenu"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-side-menu>
</ion-side-menus>
```

When I have the directive here, it is logging "LOAD THIS" two times to the console:

```
      <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
        <tester></tester> //<--- sample directive inserted here
      </ion-nav-buttons>
```

but when I move it here, it only logs "LOAD THIS" once:

```
      <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
      </ion-nav-buttons>
        <tester></tester> //<--- sample directive inserted here
```

Has anyone come across this before? I thought maybe I was calling a controller or a view or something multiple times, but this is just plain odd.

Comment: i had some same kind of issue. try giving type = "button"

Comment: @the_mahasagar I changed the directive to be an A, and did <button type="button" tester></button> and had the same results. What did you do about it?

Comment: dont know if its helpfull but try..!
<button ng-click="UpdateData()" class="button  button-block button-dark" type="button"  >
                                    Delivered
                                </button>

Comment: You're idea would help me to get the action to work, which is fine - I can get the button action works as is. But what concerns me is that the directive is loading twice. There's a potential memory leak there that I'd like to shore up. Thanks for the suggestion though.